# How do podcast apps maintain the list of podcasts and podcast episodes?

Tags: podcast

I use a third party podcast app called Overcast and I was curious how it gets the list of podcasts and episodes available, as my understanding is that it is difficult to get from iTunes. Is there a service that provides this information? I am assuming they would not maintain it themselves manually.

Answer (score 0):

Overcast likely does not reference iTunes at all.  When they learn about a new podcast, they can add the RSS feed to their database of podcasts.  That RSS feed tells any subscribers (who are using iTunes, Overcast, and any other podcast apps) what episodes are available to download.